# Form action onclick without refreshing with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple chat app. Users type in username and message and it is supposed to be inserted into database.

This is not happening with this code, and obviously I am missing something:

**FORM + SCRIPT**

```
    <form action="chat_s.php" method="post" class="send" id="form1" >
            <p>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </p>
    <div style="width: 480px; height: 400px; text-align: left;" id="DIV_CHAT">
    </div>
            <p>
    <textarea id="msg" rows="5" cols="66" name="msg" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></p>
            </p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" id="button1" name="submit" value="Send" onfocus="this.blur()"  />
    </form>
    <script>
      var frm = $('#form1');
      frm.submit(function (ev) {
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
                  alert(data);
              }
          });
          ev.preventDefault();
      });
</script>
```

This is the php file that is supposed to insert into the database the users input:

**CHAT_S.PHP**

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {}else
{
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli,$_POST['name']);
$msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['msg']);
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (username, chatdate, msg) VALUES ('$name', '$dt', '$msg')";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

But the result is nothing. It alerts nothing! And it does not insert anything into the database, it just refreshes the chat box :(

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your server code.  Watch that it gets called, check the values of the variables.

Comment: Check the response you get in the network flow. Does it return any error message?

Comment: No errors in the network flow :( Everything is green. I do not know where should I look for a problem?

Comment: Wrap your sql in a `try { (sql goes here)} catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->errorMessage()}`. If you get an error message it means there 's something wrong with your sql.

Comment: I tried this a moment ago, all is good with sql. If I put action chat_s.php and remove ajax part, it inserts the message into database.

Comment: Have you included jquery library then in your file?

Comment: Yes, this one: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I think you should put your js code enclosed by $(function(){ <your code here> });

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
  var frm = $('#form1');
  frm.submit(function (ev) {
      f = $('#form1');
      $.ajax({
          type: f.attr('method'),
          url: f.attr('action'),
          data: f.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
          }
      });
      ev.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: No luck with that also :(